# Load OpenGL function pointers using glad withing a QOpenGLWidget

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

So I am reading up on some OpenGL and I want to use the QOpenGLWidget for drawing to maybe create some other helpful UI elements later. I am using [glad](https://github.com/Dav1dde/glad) for resolving the function pointers to OpenGL but I have no idea how to use Qt's getProcAddress function!

Inside my QOpenGLWidget subclass' `initializeGL()` function I have tried:

```
if(gladLoadGLloader((GLADloadproc) currentContext()->getProcAddress) {}
```

but that did not work out since Qt's function is overloaded. When I use

```
if(gladLoadGL()) {}
```

it doesn't work either. My includes are:

```
#include <glad\glad.h>
#include "OpenGLViewport.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QOpenGLContext>
```

I have searched Mr. Google and I've had a diligent look through the Qt documentation and found nothing. I want to use GLAD just so my rendering code is not bound to Qt too tightly, in case I want to switch later.

**EDIT:** I am aiming to use the noninstanced OpenGL functions with Qt (though the documentation recommends otherwise if I recall correctly). Because then I'd be able to seemlessly switch to GLFW for providing a window etc.

Comment: Any reason for not using `initializeOpenGLFunctions()` ?

Comment: @Vallentin for that I would have to subclass `QOpenGLFunctions` as well and all my gl calls would have to be instanced.. this is something I strictly wand to avoid (see my edit).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moved solution from question to answer:

> **ANSWER:** So it turns out I just had some things mixed up, this is how I got it to work, in case anyone has the same problem:
>
> 1. add `glad.c` in your project
> 2. add the necessary headers to your include directory
> 3. the .cpp file of your `QOpenGLWidget` subclass should have following components:
>
> ---
>
> ```
> // Subclass.cpp
> #include <glad/glad.h>
> // important, subclass header file after glad!!
> // otherwise glad won't "hook"
> #include "Subclass.h"
>
> void Subclass::initializeGL()
> {
>     if(gladLoadGL()) initialized = true; // initialized is a class member here
>     else; // handle errors
> }
>
> void Subclass::paintGL()
> {
>     if(initialized); // render here
> }
> ```